# Select query to return ids based on values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a select statement that will parse an xml and return the Ids based on a condition. how do i use a loop in this case?

I have fruitIds passed in the xml. Each of the fruitids are checked in the fruitstable if it exists also if either it is fresh-0 or not-1. If sold out-(2) then it should not be taken into consideration. The SP must return distinct ids of the fruit that have IsFresh set to 0 or 1

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Fruits]      
 @Data XML 
AS

BEGIN TRY

SET @Data = '<Fruits>
 <Fruit FruitID="1"></Fruit>
  <Fruit FruitID="2"></Fruit>
 </Fruits>'

SELECT DISTINCT(FruitType)      
from dbo.FruitsTable
where FruitID =  (SELECT    Fruit.cols.value('@FruitID', 'INT') FruitID
            FROM   @Data.nodes('/Fruits/Fruit') Fruit(cols))
 AND (Fruit.IsFresh = 0 OR Fruit.IsFresh = 1)                      
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH  
END CATCH 
GO
```

> ```
> FruitsTable
>
>       Composite Key = fruitid,buyerid
>          FruitID IsFresh BuyerID(this if FK)
>          1            0     1
>          2            1     2
>          3            0     2
>          4            0     3
>          5            2     1
>          1            1     2
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Senthil, You are very close, meaning your logic is sound, just your syntax is off.  You need to use IN instead of "=" (IN checks if the value is in a set) and fix your table aliasing:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT f.FruitId
from    dbo.FruitsTable f
where   f.FruitID in (
            SELECT Fruit.cols.value('@FruitID', 'INT') FruitID
            FROM   @Data.nodes('/Fruits/Fruit') Fruit(cols))
        AND (f.IsFresh in (0,1))
```